# Generate HATEOAS links on Spring MVC methods with optional hyphenated parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I'm trying to implement an [OGC API - Features](https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features) service using Spring Boot. The specification includes links to self, parent collections and such, so I figured Spring HATEOAS could help with that. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with the `bbox-crs` parameter.

An example demonstration:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

  @GetMapping(path = "/link", produces = "application/geo+json")
  public Link getLink(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "bbox-crs") String bboxCrs) {
    return linkTo(methodOn(DemoController.class).getLink(bboxCrs))
        .withSelfRel()
        .expand()
        .withType("application/geo+json");
  }

}
```

Test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class DemoApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void getLinkWithParam() throws Exception {
    String expectedJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
        new Link("http://localhost/link?bbox-crs=hello").withType("application/geo+json"));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/link?bbox-crs=hello"))
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/geo+json"))
        .andExpect(content().json(expectedJson));
  }

  @Test
  public void getLinkNoParam() throws Exception {
    String expectedJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
        new Link("http://localhost/link").withType("application/geo+json"));

    mockMvc.perform(get("/link"))
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/geo+json"))
        .andExpect(content().json(expectedJson));
  }

}
```

The first test succeeds, but the second test fails with the error `Illegal character in path at index 23: http://localhost/link{?bbox-crs}`.

According to [issue #799](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/799), this is working as intended, as the URI Template spec does not allow for hyphens in variable names. I'm trying to build an URI, though, not an URI Template. Is there some way to 
achieve what I'm after? Maybe by configuring Spring or by creating the link in a different way?

Comment: Did you get the answer? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @user3768904 Not really. I made a utility class that create links a bit differently: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/1168#issuecomment-613288622

Comment: thanks for giving idea :)